# How to create JavaFX project in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I click on New Project-->Java FX --> Manage Platforms -- > Add Platforms ---> Then I select java-8-openjdk-amd64 --> next--> then the platform sources is not filling out automatically then click on finish button after there is no table for JavaFX, I kinda confused what can be the problem what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what JDK you install?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_121"  @YCF_L

Comment: What version of Netbeans are you using?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson 8.2

Comment: For OpenJDK you are required to have OpenJFX installed too (at least on linux systems)

Comment: im on linux @FibreFox

Comment: @FibreFox thank i got it now, you saved my life !